# Box email - subset of domains have stopped working

Tags: email-server

I am hosting a Box instance on a Bytemark server.  I host twenty or so email domains there (for my business and family) and have been for five plus years.

Yesterday, two of the domains have been receiving email very sporadically.  Test emails sent from some (external) servers have never arrived.  Some have arrived six hours later.

Other domains served seem to be absolutely fine.  For example, I send an email to one of the broken domains and cc one of the working ones.  The working one immediately arrives; the other takes 6 hours.  I've repeated this test multiple times.

I've looked at the Box admin status page, and nothing seems amiss; nor can I see an obvious pattern between the domains that are failing.

I'm at a complete loss!

**UPDATE**

Many emails are starting to come through, but with a 12-24 hour delay.

Comment: I would first check if any of your sending/receiving domains/IPs have been blacklisted. One such tool is https://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx I don't know if there is much you can do about it but it might explain some issues if you find any blacklisted.

Comment: Cheers.  Only one blacklist - UCEPROTECTL3 - I don't know if that's a big one.

Comment: What does the headers show? They may indicate where the mail was held up. What does incoming logs show? Was the message rejected by the MX?

Comment: X-Greylist: delayed 43271 seconds by postgrey-1.35 at box.mydomain.com
So that's a big red flag!

Comment: This sounds like `postgrey` doing its job. The length of time for the sending server to re-send is based on its own configuration. If these are very large senders, they may have more than one sending server and not configured to use the same server for a given domain.

Comment: This is the other part which looks relevant - where can I find why (if) it was originally refused?

Received: from AM7PR09MB3799.eurprd09.prod.outlook.com (2603:10a6:20b:de::22)
 by DB7PR09MB2378.eurprd09.prod.outlook.com (2603:10a6:10:4a::12) with
 Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2,
 cipher=blah) id 15.20.5061.24; Sat, 12 Mar
 2022 15:45:51 +0000
Received: from AM7PR09MB3799.eurprd09.prod.outlook.com
 ([fe80::d72:e879:3b8:e625]) by AM7PR09MB3799.eurprd09.prod.outlook.com
 ([fe80::d72:e879:3b8:e625%5]) with mapi id 15.20.5061.026; Sat, 12 Mar 2022
 15:45:51 +0000

Comment: Use `grep messageidstring /var/log/mail.log` to find all of the transactions with the message.

Comment: I'm finding it hard to divine the message id string from the headers